# how to fix "Another git process seems to be running in this repository"

Tags: git, gitlab, git-flow, hotfix

start project by git flow
and in process bugfix not commit finish process see error to other order git:
Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.

remove index.lock and remove branches
delete repository
restart system
.
.
.
connot stop process git

Answer (score 0):

Try to run in the console the next command: `ps aux | grep git`.

This will list all the Git processes that are currently running on your system, then you can use the `kill` command with the number of the process.